# Click button to slide div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code but I'm stuck. I need it to be closed when the page opens and then slide down when the button is clicked. Any help?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/9cdYR/

```js
$('#slide_button').click(function() {
  $('#slide').animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 1500, function() {});
});
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#slide {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide">
  Slide content<br /> Slide content<br /> Slide content<br />
</div>
<div id="content">
  Content<br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br />
</div>

<button id="slide_button">Slide it</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this behaviour change your jquery code to

```
$('#slide_button').click(function() {
  $('#slide').animate({
    height: 'show'
  }, 1500, function() {
  });
});
$('#slide').animate({
  height: 'hide'
}, 0, function() {
});
```

But if you want the button to still toogle in every click change the height property to 'toggle'

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("slide_button").onclick = function() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("slide").style.height) == 0) {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.height = "60px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.height = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#slide {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  height : 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">
  Slide content<br /> Slide content<br /> Slide content<br />
</div>
<div id="content">
  Content<br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br />
</div>

<button id="slide_button">Slide it</button>
```